# present perfect: has settled for ages

Tags: present-perfect

Is "settled" used properly in the following?

> John has settled in New York for ages.

Should 'settled" be changed to "been settled"?

Comment: You are correct. To my American ears, "settled" describes a state, an action, and a process. Take your pick.

Comment: *Settled* doesn't sound correct, because "to settle" is a kind of one-time action, not a process.  But *been settled* also sounds a little strange, because since *settle* is a change of state, it sounds weird with "for ages".  I would probably just say "John settled in New York ages ago."  Is this a sentence you came up with yourself, or did you see it somewhere?

Comment: @stangdon: I'm good with ***I've been content** here for many years*, and I don't really see why ***settled*** should be any different when it's effectively an "adjectival" use of the past participle. And there are plenty of written instances of [*(They) **have been settled here for many** (years)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22have+been+settled+here+for+many%22) in Google Books.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the correct match with "for ages" is "has been settled". Plain past tense would work with a reference to a time in the past.

Here are some examples with different verb forms:

*John has been settled in New York for ages.*

*John settled in New York ages ago.*

*John is settling in New York, after wanting to live there for ages.*

*John had been settled in New York for ages before he suddenly bought an RV and started living as a nomad.*

*John could have been settled in New York for ages, if he hadn't quit his first job there.*